# CakePHP: make requests to external API's before inserting data

Tags: php, cakephp, logic

I'm developing an app with cakephp 2.x, I'm really a newbie to cakephp and this could be a silly question.

The app will be used to store social network posts (youtube videos, facebook posts, twitter tweets, instagram photos).

The logic is very simple:
1. User finds an interesting post on any of the social networks listed.
2. User copy/paste the URL of the post and selects the type of content.
3. When User hits submit, the app has to make the request to the proper API and get the data of the post.

I don't have problems with getting the information (I can handle the part of the API requests). What I don't know is where to make those requests. **Is it in the model or the controller? What do you think is the best approach for this requirement?**

I know that there are callbacks to the model (beforeSave, beforeValidate), any guidance on this subject would be very helpful.

I don't need the actual code, I just need some light on the logic, what cakephp callbacks I have to use or create or even if I have to create components or plugins... and as I said, where to put them.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Well, according to the MVC your model should be doing only business logic. The controller acts as an intermediary between your view and model, in this scenario (and in most web development) the controller is receiving data from the user (specifically from the View layer) and this data will be later sent and processed by your model, now, the principle of MVC is the separation of concerns, your model doesn't care where the data come from or how you got it, your model just want to do its job. That's why I would get the data from the controller, that is, make the api calls in your controller.

Comment: Agreed, though I'd probably put it in a component in case you'd want to reuse the logic, and to keep the controller cleaner.

Comment: Absolutely! but always in the Controller layer.

Comment: Agree. However your controller should only get the data. Probably still pass the data to the model for processing your logic before rendering it directly in view.